# How do I obtain an Android Conference Call's Children?

Tags: android

I am building up a custom Android call interface and need to obtain a conference call's children call objects to manage merged calls.

Here is the code that handles a new call.  I assumed that if the new call added represents a conference call then I should be able to access those children and drop individual calls, split individual calls, register callbacks for each child call, etc.

```
public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
    Log.i("MyCallService", "Call state: " + call.getState());

    if(call.getDetails().hasProperty(Call.Details.PROPERTY_CONFERENCE)) {
            Log.i("MyCallService", "Conference call entered with " + call.getChildren().size()
                    + " participants.");
               return;
        }
    //...
}
```

For some reason, no matter how many calls have been merged the `call.getChildren().size()` is always `zero`.  Is this an issue with Android or is there some other way I need to go about accessing a conference call's children?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answered my own question.  Should anyone run across this incredibly obscure problem again, the problem is it takes a second for Android to actually add the calls as children even though a new conference call is registered immediately.  If you create a callback with

```
public void onChildrenChanged(Call call, List<Call> children) {
    super.onChildrenChanged(call, children);
}
```

you will see those new children being added and can then run `.getChildren()` on that conference call object.